# How to send Gcm notification to one app to other

Tags: php, android, curl, notifications

I am wondering if it is possible to send push notifications to different Android applications. I can already send a push notification in same application but I want to send notification to different applications of mine. I have user application and driver application. I need to send push notification when user create order and driver get notification that "A new order is come" after driver accept. Acknowledgement notification get back to user.

I am using two different Google API for both Application, I think, its not good way...

Please give idea about this. ? thx

Comment: Mollie, its quite confusing, you have 2 apps, one for user and another one is for driver. Then what is the problem? Your case will work as per you asked.

Comment: its also confusing me and my team, but both application database  is same

Comment: Ya then what is the problem? If you can do this one way then its easy to acknowledge also.

Comment: its working when send notification to same app, now am asking its possible to send notification to one app to other

Comment: then it's like messaging right? @mollie

Comment: @mollie its totally depends on server, because Push notification will be fired from server, so just tell server people to do it.

Comment: Its push notification, and want to know that Its possible with two different Google API or i have to use one gcm api for both application.

Comment: if you ask, pushnotification from server with two app means surely possible but within two app push notification is not possible @mollie

Comment: @Spark some one tell me , its only possible when in both application  Gcm api is same , i am used Diff GCM in app and now don't want to change coz its takes long time.

Comment: @mollie push notification with 2 mobiles are not possible, but yes, you can make it using your server, generate 2 push from server and itsfine if you have 2 different API's use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

push notification with 2 different apps are possible,i make it one database for both apps for save token id, generate 2 push notification. its working fine

Answer (score 0):

What you want is possible and not that strange at all, you have two applications registered for push in the developer console with two projects ids and want each of your Android application to be able to receive notifications from both ? 
If thats what you want its possible you just need to register to both sender ids in the android applications check.

https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#multi-senders

basically:

```
...
    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                    }
                    regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID_ONE, SENDER_ID_TWO);
....
```

Comment: I am  tried to getting your point, but explain some thing that, I have to change use same sender id or other .

Comment: You have two Google API projects registered for sending push you, so if you want an Android application to receive notifications from both when you're registering a device in Google servers for push the method `gcm.register()` accepts a list of sender id's to allow for that case